# consultas automaticas a mongodb una vez al mes

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, bash, mongoose

tengo que realizar una operación por cada documento de una colección un día especifico del mes y guardar los resultados en otros documento de diferentes colecciones, mi pregunta seria cual es la mejor forma de realizar esto, seria con un script en bash, un cron en nodejs.

Que es lo que realizo:
Traigo todos los archivos y guardo en dos diferentes colecciones mientras realiza el ciclo.
Problemas:

- No se cuántos documentos sean (posiblemente muchos) entonces si uno ¿fallara cómo podría recobrar el ciclo?
- Al cargar los archivos en memoria en dado caso sean demasiados ¿sería mejor realizar esto con un ´´´worker´´?

he utilizado [cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) y a funcionado pero no consigo entender si en ese tiempo la tarea se repetirá constantemente ya que al parecer lo hace, dejo un ejemplo de mi código

```
 pepinosModelo.find()
  .exec()
  .then(pepinos => {

    pepinos.forEach(pepino => {

      let frecuencia = pepino.frecuente();
      let nuevoTrans = [{
        chocolate:true,
        abena:"de dos a tres porcines",
        lsd: "No aplica"
      }];


      nuevoTrans.push({
        chocolate:false,
        coco:"Completo",
        lsd: "Aplica"
      });

      return TransModel.create(nuevoTrans)
      .then((trans) => {

        fumadorModelo
        .update({
          pepino: pepino._id
        }, { 
          'comprador': false,
          'nuevaDocis': zero 
        })
        .exec()
        .then((usuario) => { 
          pepino.cambio += frecuencia;
          pepino.balance = zero;
          pepino.puntos = zero;
          return pepino
          .save()
          .then(() => {
            console.log(´fin actualizacion usuario ciclo ${usuario}´);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Es preocupante lo de _"una vez al mes"_, ¿y si se corta la luz? ¿y si se cierra el programa? Pueden pasar muchas cosas, en mi caso mi compu no dura un mes prendida por los insectos, o directamente se llena la memoria... Yo te recomendaría guardar en disco un archivo con todas las fechas futuras de cada mes, y un booleano que indique si tal tarea se ejecutó. Entonces vas comparando la fecha actual con la del archivo.

Answer (score 1):

quizas te sirva ésto:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-cron

Saludos

Comment: Pienso que es lo que necesita, pero no es una "respuesta" como tal, si no un comentario. Podrías añadir un ejemplo usando el paquete para complementarla más. Un saludo.

Comment: Si, lo siento respondi mal pero tampoco pidio ejemplos solo cuál es posiblemente la mejor forma. Por lo tanto mi respuesta correcta sería "Un cron en node" y el paquete que recomiendo es el que comente hace un momento.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta voy a probar la librería gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo he ocupado este paquete: [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).
Podrías usar un loop para trabajar n cantidad de archivos. Si uno fallá maneja las exepciones y al final genera un reporte de archivos o updates fallidos.

Mientras tu servidor tenga buenas caracteristicas puedes soportar n cantidad de archivos.

El uso es simple, pongo un ejemplo cualquiera:

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

var manejoDeArchivos = require('./server/services/v1/manejoDeArchivos');
cron.schedule('0 0 1 * *', function () {
    manejoDeArchivos.execute();
});
```

Después en el archivo manejoDeArchivos.js puedes leer los archivos con un paquete, si son csv te recomiendo [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) y trabajar con mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User');

exports.execute = function () {

    var data = {
        "puntos.temporales" : 600
    };
    User.update({isActive: true}, {$set: data}, {multi: true}, function (err, docs) {
        if(err)
            console.error('Errot at executing cron job. Error: ' + err, {colors: true});
        if(docs) {
            console.log(docs);
            console.dir('Cron job executed correctly', {colors: true});
        }
    })
};
```